# Route 53 domain gives DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN for certain browsers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I bought a domain from route 53. I added an A record with the server IP(static IP) to the host zone. I followed [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/get-a-domain/) but when I look at my domain I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN sometimes. I have:

- Created an A record of domain
- Gave the same EC2 IP to the A record
- Changed the Security group HTTP and HTTPS of EC2 for port 80 and 443 to all

It works for some browsers and does not work for others.
Works for - Samsung's Galaxy Browser, Google Chrome incognito mode
Does not work for- Google Chrome normal, Samsung's Galaxy Browser incognite, Opera both normal and incognito.

My ec2 instance is launched by ecs so my security group is the amazon-ecs-cli-setup-projectname-EcsSecurityGroup-XXXXX.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: when you changed record its take around 48-72 hours to reflect across the globe to all ISPs.